# Почему возникает TypeError при создании объекта модели?

Tags: python, model, mvc, view, django

Пытаюсь в View создать объект **`post = ProfileEntry`**, при выполнении вылетает ошибка:

> TypeError at /accounts/profile/
>
> 'wall' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

##### Модель:

```
class ProfileEntry(models.Model):
    author = User
    wall = User
    context = wmd_models
```

##### Место ошибки:

```
post = ProfileEntry(context = cd['context'], author = request.user, wall = user)
```

Comment: Дополни полностью твою модель.

Comment: @chernysh, написал всё, как есть...

Comment: Какая версия django используется?
Или я не врубаюсь, но поля в модели должны быть такими: author = models.ForeignKey(User) и т.п.

Comment: О, спасибо, переделайте в ответ и я его приму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как нужно оформить модель:

```
class ProfileEntry(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    wall = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_wall')
    context = models.TextField()  # Предположил, что это текст
```

Comment: @chernysh,

    from wmd.models import MarkDownField as wmd_models
    context = wmd_models

Так что, по сути, да.